# Image into SQLite and not to gallery

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I have a requirement to store an image in the android app and it shouldn't appear in the gallery.So, I decided to have SQLite database in the app 'assets' folder and I would store the imagepath into database. The problem is, if not into SDCard, then how do i get the imagepath? or is there a way i could hide the images captured by my app from appearing in gallery. Below is the code i am currently using to store images in external directory.

```
photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment .DIRECTORY_PICTURES), imageName); 
//imageName=current timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method to save images into internal storage (and save the returned path to your sqlite)

```
    private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String filename){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.d("dir", directory.toString());
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,filename);
    Log.d("path", mypath.toString());

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("ingesteld path", directory.getAbsolutePath());
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Load the images using:

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path, String name)
{
    try {
        File f=new File(path, name);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));

        // Do something with your bitmap
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Hope this is of any use.

Comment: Thank you Opoo. I am using ByteArrayOutputStream instead of FileOutputStream to write to the memory.Is that appreciable? also, can you help me understand which path is stored into database..is it this path to -"/data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir"?

Comment: I'm not sure if it works the same, the path stored is "/data/data/com.example.app/app_imageDir" in my case using the method used above.  String path = saveToInternalStorage(bitmap, name);
                    question.setImagePath(path);